# get same plot by using ggplot function and basic plot function

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown

I record analysis process by rmarkdown unsing knitr(html_document).

i use `ggplot2::ggplot()` and `graphics::plot()` case by case.
but figure size font size, plot area are different.

I want to get same plot using the both plot function.
color, axis, ... are no problem.
how can i setup?

I hope to setup easily and simplify, like only write chunk setup.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()

plot(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)
```

Comment: Have you tried searching on "theme classic"?

Comment: I use theme_bw() .
color is no problem but arrange plot area size etc.